# В чём причина сообщеня did not write partition table to disk?

Tags: linux, archlinux

Пытаюсь поставить ArchLinux при разметки диска прога cfdisk пишет

> did not write partition table to disk

и соответственно ни чего не размечает.

Bios обычный, пробовал на разных жёстких дисках на них всё так же хотя другие варианты linux без проблем ставятся.

Comment: о какой программе всё же речь, `fdisk` или `cfdisk`? и что __именно__ делаешь с точностью до деталей?

Comment: cfdisk выдаёт такое сообщение, если на вопрос "Are you sure you want to write the partition table to disk?" не был введён ответ "yes".

Comment: @Fat-Zer поравил cfdisk

Comment: @Akina а разве буквы "y" не достаточно нужно словом прописывать ?

Comment: В исходном коде `cfdisk.c` сравнение выполняется с литералом 'yes': `if (rc <= 0 || (strcasecmp(buf, "yes") != 0 && strcasecmp(buf, _("yes")) != 0)) { info = _("Did not write partition table to disk."); break;`. Операция-то опасная, отсюда и строгости...

Comment: @VargSieg, очевидно, нет... это классическая «усиленная» защита от дурака... кстати, как видно из исходников, в локализованном варианте «да» также работает... бессмысленный, но приятный штрих...